# I am trying to access(read, append) a .txt file in Python program and it shows:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, file

This is a part of my code that is supposedly causing the error:

```
in_file = open(os.path.join(args.meta, 'final_meta.txt'), 'r')
out_file = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'output.csv'), 'a', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['wav_filename', 'wav_filesize', 'transcript'])
```

I tried adding 'rb' instead of 'r' but it gives another error shown below:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to open it as a binary file if it's text data. I would think that whatever you're doing (later) with in_file is the issue, and that it's probable that in_file is malformed somehow.

Comment: You've cut out the part where you actually do something with `in_file`.

Comment: You should post the full error message

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: This is happening to your in_file right? Try to open it in a text editor like notepad++ and see what is its encoding. Then use that when opening the file,or convert it to utf8.

Comment: `for line in in_file:
                fname, ftext, _ = line.split("\"")
                fname = fname.strip()[1:].strip() + '.wav'
                ftext = ftext.strip().lower()
                ftext = replace_func(ftext).replace("  "," ").strip()
                ftext = re.sub(r"(\d+)", lambda x: num2words.num2words(int(x.group(0))), ftext)
                fdur, fsr = get_audio_info(str(os.path.join(args.wav, fname)))` This is what I am doing to my in_file later.